# Alert not working within PHP Code

Tags: php

Why my alert box is not working. Anyone can help me for find out my mistake?

I tried various way. But its not working. finally I try this way. Even this is also not working.

My aim is, if multi query executed successfully means, alert the success message then reload to the another page.

Please Help me.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

if (isset($_GET['insertQuery'])) {
  include("connection/connectionMysqli.php");

  if (!mysqli_multi_query($conn,$_SESSION['insertQuery'])) {
    echo "<script>alert('Faild Due to server Problem.!!!');window.refresh(true);</script>";
  } else {
    unset($_SESSION['insertQuery']);
    echo "<script>alert('Success');</script>";
    header("Location:bluk_resource_booking.php?successInsert=1");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: remove `window.refresh(true)`

Comment: Sorry I can't get you. Can you give some brief explanation. Thank you.

Comment: `echo "<script>alert('Faild Due to server Problem.!!!');window.refresh(true);</script>";` here remove window.refresh(true)

Comment: Ya thank you for your suport. But I removed that line. Now too alert function not working. Directly reloaded to "bluk_resource_booking.php" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `header("Location: ...")` will cause PHP to respond with a [`302 Found`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) status, rather than a [`200 Success`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) status.

A [3xx status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) will cause the browser to do a redirect, ignoring anything you send in the body (including JavaScript).

---

Instead you can alert and then redirect using JavaScript.

```
} else {
  unset($_SESSION['insertQuery']);
  echo "<script>alert('Success'); window.location.href = 'bluk_resource_booking.php?successInsert=1';</script>";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jasny. This is very helpful for me to solve my problem.